# jTable buttons for MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

Hello again i have this code here

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package carrent;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author INFO COMPUTERS
 */
public class booking extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form booking
     */
    public booking() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

        entityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("rental?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNullPU").createEntityManager();
        booking_1Query = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Booking_1 b");
        booking_1List = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : booking_1Query.getResultList();
        carQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Car c");
        carList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : carQuery.getResultList();
        agencyQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Agency a");
        agencyList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : agencyQuery.getResultList();
        customerQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customer c");
        customerList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : customerQuery.getResultList();
        carQuery1 = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Car c");
        carList1 = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : carQuery1.getResultList();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tbl = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tblcar = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, booking_1List, tbl);
        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding.ColumnBinding columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${returnDate}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Return Date");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(java.util.Date.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${bookingDate}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Booking Date");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(java.util.Date.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${customerId}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Customer Id");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${agencyId}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Agency Id");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${carId}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Car Id");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${bookingNumber}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Booking Number");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
        bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);
        jTableBinding.bind();

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tbl);

        jButton1.setText("Back");
        jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, carList1, tblcar);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${id}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Id");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${status}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Status");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${producer}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Producer");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${carName}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Car Name");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${basePricePerDay}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Base Price Per Day");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Float.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${dateOfManufacturing}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Date Of Manufacturing");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(java.util.Date.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${color}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Color");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${registrationNumber}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Registration Number");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);
        jTableBinding.bind();

        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(tblcar);

        jButton4.setText("Delete Booking");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Update Booking");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setText("Add Booking");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Return Date");

        jLabel2.setText("Booking Date");

        jLabel3.setText("Customer Id");

        jLabel4.setText("Agency Id");

        jLabel5.setText("Car Id");

        org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, tbl, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.returnDate}"), jTextField1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, tbl, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.bookingDate}"), jTextField2, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, tbl, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.customerId}"), jTextField3, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, tbl, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.agencyId}"), jTextField4, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, tbl, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.carId}"), jTextField5, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        jLabel6.setText("Booking Number");

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, tbl, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.bookingNumber}"), jTextField6, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 1182, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jButton5)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton4)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton2))
                            .addComponent(jLabel6))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 730, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                                .addGap(73, 73, 73)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 59, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField3)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField2)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField5))))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 114, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(197, 197, 197)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addComponent(jButton4)
                            .addComponent(jButton5)))))
        );

        bindingGroup.bind();

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        this.dispose();
                MainMenu mm = new MainMenu();
                mm.show();
    }                                     

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(booking.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(booking.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(booking.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(booking.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new booking().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private java.util.List<carrent.Agency> agencyList;
    private javax.persistence.Query agencyQuery;
    private java.util.List<carrent.Booking_1> booking_1List;
    private javax.persistence.Query booking_1Query;
    private java.util.List<carrent.Car> carList;
    private java.util.List<carrent.Car> carList1;
    private javax.persistence.Query carQuery;
    private javax.persistence.Query carQuery1;
    private java.util.List<carrent.Customer> customerList;
    private javax.persistence.Query customerQuery;
    private javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    private javax.swing.JTable tbl;
    private javax.swing.JTable tblcar;
    private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

i have connected the jTable with my database table car how can i make an add button could someone help i am using MySQL Workbench as my Database and the design looks like this

[image: i have connected the jTextBox with database]

i have connected my textboxes with database via bind

Comment: you want to add what? MySQL entry through your application? I used to do it like this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Comment: i want to add a new record

Comment: Yea, it should be very easy to do with JDBC for MySQL

Comment: i can see the contents of the table but i cant edit or update them i get the following error :

    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"          java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.util.Date to java.lang.String

Comment: well then you need to use `Date().toString();` method